# Android can't extend Firebase Messaging Service

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging in my application, I had implemented all settings to use this service, but when I try to extend `FirebaseMessagingService` in my class it gives me error and it can't find it at all, I can't even `import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService` as shown in the picture:

[image]

I had added all the code required:
I added this to app gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0' 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this to the module gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

this is the manifest code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

and I added the google json file to the app.
So if anybody can help me please

Comment: invalidating caches\restarting android studio helped me..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to use messaging, you have to add the messaging module. Right now you only added the core module.

So go ahead and include

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```

All the available modules can be found at the bottom of https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Also note there is no need to include the core dependency manually. It will be transitively included when you add firebase-messaging.

Comment: @ArthurThompson suggestion worked. "no need to include the core dependency manually". So it worked after I deleted firebase:core